# Why does this not work for finding the Maclaurin series of this expression?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Okay, so I supposed to find the Maclaurin serie for the xpression $g(x)=e^{1-x}$.
I thought I could use a well-know Maclaurin serie:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n}{n!}=e^t$$
and then just substitute for $t=1-x$. But my teacher said this do not work, but why? Can one only use substitution when the only thing you want to change is a factor in front of $x$?

Comment: You get $$e^{1-x}=\sum\frac{(1-x)^n}{n!}$$ which does not have the form $\sum a_nx^n$, So you need some work to put it into that form.

Comment: Just substituting $t=1-x$ doesn't give you the Maclaurin series, but will instead give you a Taylor series centered around another point.

Comment: Ohh, of course! A Maclaurin series is only $x^n$ and not $(1-x)^n$. I get it now. Thank you so much both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$e^{1-x}= e(e^{-x})$$

$$e^{-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^n}{n!}$$

You can take it from there.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it now: $e^{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^ne}{n!}*x^n$